# October CMS SimpleTree backend form

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

Im trying to implement a parent/child relationship using the Simple Tree Trait.

I've attached it as sad in the [documentation](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/traits#simple-tree)

In the back end I used the form builder to add a relatioship field to make a parent element selectable, the fields.yaml file

```
fields:
    name:
        label: 'name'
        oc.commentPosition: ''
        span: full
        required: 1
        type: text
    image:
        label: 'image'
        oc.commentPosition: ''
        mode: image
        span: full
        type: mediafinder
    parent_id:
        label: Relation
        oc.commentPosition: ''
        nameFrom: name
        descriptionFrom: description
        span: auto
        type: relation
```

The error model does not contain a definition of parent_id.

```
<?php namespace depcore\parts\Models;
use Model;

/**
 * Model
 */
class Series extends Model
{
    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation;
    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\SimpleTree;

    /*
     * Disable timestamps by default.
     * Remove this line if timestamps are defined in the database table.
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /*
     * Validation
     */
    public $rules = [
    ];

    /**
     * @var string The database table used by the model.
     */
    public $table = 'depcore_parts_series';

    /**
     * Relations
     */
    public $attachOne = [
      'image' =>'System\Models\File'
    ];

}
```

I could not find any information in the documentation how to implement the relationship so that user can select a parent element when adding a new one.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so after digging around the solution is quite simple in the backend form for the model instead `parent_id` the field should be `parent` so the complete code would look like

```
fields:
    name:
        label: 'name'
        oc.commentPosition: ''
        span: full
        required: 1
        type: text
    image:
        label: 'image'
        oc.commentPosition: ''
        mode: image
        span: full
        type: mediafinder
    parent:
        label: 'parent'
        oc.commentPosition: ''
        nameFrom: name
        descriptionFrom: description
        span: auto
        type: relation
```